# Modifing line after match on a RHEL based system

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, configuration

I am looking for a sane way (I originally looked at `sed` but I believe it is convoluted) to enable sections in a yum repo.

My Puppet repo is:

```
[puppetlabs-products]
name=Puppet Labs Products El 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/products/$basearch
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[puppetlabs-deps]
name=Puppet Labs Dependencies El 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/dependencies/$basearch
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[puppetlabs-devel]
name=Puppet Labs Devel El 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/devel/$basearch
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1

[puppetlabs-products-source]
name=Puppet Labs Products El 7 - $basearch - Source
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/products/SRPMS
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1

[puppetlabs-deps-source]
name=Puppet Labs Source Dependencies El 7 - $basearch - Source
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/dependencies/SRPMS
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1

[puppetlabs-devel-source]
name=Puppet Labs Devel El 7 - $basearch - Source
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/devel/SRPMS
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
```

I would like to be able to match (in this instance) `[puppetlabs-devel]` and throw the enable flag from `0` to `1`. What is a sane way to do this in RHEL based systems? This must be an automated solution as this is part of a bootscript and should have no interaction.

I was fudging with this, but never really could get it working

```
cat /etc/yum.repos.d/puppetlabs.repo |awk '/\[puppetlabs-devel\]/{print;getline;$0="enabled=1"}1'
```

*Expected Output*

```
[puppetlabs-products]
name=Puppet Labs Products El 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/products/$basearch
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[puppetlabs-deps]
name=Puppet Labs Dependencies El 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/dependencies/$basearch
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[puppetlabs-devel]
name=Puppet Labs Devel El 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/devel/$basearch
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
enabled=1  ## This portion changed 
gpgcheck=1

[puppetlabs-products-source]
name=Puppet Labs Products El 7 - $basearch - Source
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/products/SRPMS
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1

[puppetlabs-deps-source]
name=Puppet Labs Source Dependencies El 7 - $basearch - Source
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/dependencies/SRPMS
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Post the expected output given that input and explain what a "RHEL based" system is if that's relevant, or remove the text about ti if it's not.

Comment: @EdMorton Will post output in a minute, RHEL based as in this system could be Fedora, Redhat Linux, CentOS etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` you will have something like this:

```
sed '/\[puppetlabs-devel\]/,/^\[/s/^enabled=0/enabled=1/' puppetlabs.repo
```

This expression will search between `[puppetlabs-devel]` and the next `[`, changing the line that starts with `enabled=0`.